# How to fill in a shape and not have "gaps" between the border and the fill-in colour

Tags: krita

Say I was to make a flower, and fill in a petal - a gap between the border and the filled-in colour would appear, and it doesn't look nice.

How do I avoid that problem without having to manually fill it in?

Thank you!

***Note:*** *I am using Krita.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the tool options for the Fill tool, set the *Grow Selection* and *Feathering Radius* settings to 1px. This should give a nice smooth result. Obviously, you can adjust these as you like, but having both set at zero will cause problems.

Example, settings at 0px on the left, compared to 1px on the right

[image]

Comment: This works! Thank you very much!

Comment: However, a small area around the outline shows up: https://ibb.co/tMcvK1Y

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Do I have to ask this in a different question? Thanks!

Comment: @Crownie - not sure what I'm looking at there to be honest.  I assumed you had an object drawn using a fairly sharp black line on a white canvas, and that you were trying to fill it.  Maybe try adjusting the threshold slider as well. You'll need to experiment I think.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thank you!